# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I'm trying to have a datePicker in my webPage, but I'm constantly coming through the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function EmpDetails.jsp:21
(anonymous function) EmpDetails.jsp:21
j jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
n.extend.ready jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
I jquery-2.1.0.min.js:2
```

**Script Files**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/commons/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/commons/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/commons/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/StuDetails_By_Fac.js"></script>
```

**Code Causing Error**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#dob").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

**JSP Code**

```
<s:textfield id="dob"  key="" cssClass="text-input required" label="DOB" labelSeparator=""/>
```

Sorry for repeated question,as none of them proved helpful.

Comment: What code is there at EmpDetails.jsp:21

Comment: Check the reference of jquery UI; Position of your script tag.

Comment: @RajuRudru-$("#dob").datepicker();

Comment: Are you loading multiple versions of jQuery? Check network tab in debugger.